# Area 51 accounts

Tags: discussion, area51

Can I get my area 51 sights on to my accounts area on my beta sights so I can follow its progress? I would like to know when it makes it to Beta without having to continually check.

Answer (score 1):

If you either follow (in the Definition section of the proposal) or commit (in the Commitment section) to a proposal, you'll get an email when the site launches to beta. I think you have to be committed to get in when it first goes into private beta.

Comment: I am committed and I did get that email, now what?

Comment: @morahhochman, which proposal? Has it launched into [beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta), or is it still in the commitment phase? If the former, you should be able to go visit the site. If the latter, you'll get an email when the proposal accumulates enough commitment and launches to beta. You can speed this process along by recruiting people to commit to the proposal.